# Z3 Solver outputting the satisfying model?

Tags: z3

In Z3, if the input script is written in SMTLib format, is it possible to output the model (value assignments satisfying the model)? The get-model returns an interpretation satisfying the constraints. Is there any way to extract the concrete values from these interpretations. I am aware that we can use the python/C++ API to get model values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `get-value`, here's a minimal example (rise4fun link: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/wR81 ):

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)
(assert (>= (* 2 x) (+ y z)))
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(declare-fun g (Int Int) Int)
(assert (< (f x) (g x x)))
(assert (> (f y) (g x x)))
(check-sat) ; sat
(get-model) ; returns:
; (model 
;  (define-fun z () Int
;    0)
;  (define-fun y () Int
;    (- 38))
;  (define-fun x () Int
;    0)
;  (define-fun g ((x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Int
;    (ite (and (= x!1 0) (= x!2 0)) 0
;      0))
;  (define-fun f ((x!1 Int)) Int
;    (ite (= x!1 0) (- 1)
;    (ite (= x!1 (- 38)) 1
;      (- 1))))
;)
(get-value (x)) ; returns ((x 0))
(get-value ((f x))) ; returns (((f x) (- 1)))
```

You'd potentially then have to parse this depending on what you're trying to do, etc.

For more details, check out the SMT-LIB standard:

http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml

The latest version is: http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.0-r12.09.09.pdf

You can see some examples of `get-value` on page 39 / figure 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I will look into it. Trying to get a grip on the Z3 solver.